# menu bar positioning problem at the bottom of jQuery mobile page on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I made an application using jQuery mobile, but now I have a huge problem. I can't make the bottom menu bar to appear in the bottom of the page on iPhone. It works on nokia c6, and desktop browsers. I used `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`. When I remove these properties it makes it tighter. See images.

- [Without positioning properties](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/img0478.png/)
- [Without positioning properties](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/img0476p.png/)
- [With positioning](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/202/img0470.png/)
- [With positioning](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/img0471.png/)

Comment: Labiden! =) Let's see your code, preferably in http://jsfiddle.net/ have you tried putting it inside the `<div data-role="footer">` ?

Comment: Labdien (: http://radionsm.thelordraimonds.info/apps/iphone/#mainpage heres the app. Now i hace commented out position absolute and bottom 0, but yes its in data-role footer.

Comment: can you clarify where you want it to be - bottom of the page (lappuses) or bottom of the window (loga).

Comment: Bottom of the page, but if the page is smaller, than window. I changed some code, so I need to recheck it on Iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it appear on the bottom of the screen then you will have to check if the div containing your page is at least as long as the screen. Something like:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow orientationchange', function () {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    if ($(this).find('div[data-role="content"]').height() < window_height) {
        //window height minus the height of the header bar
        var th = (window_height - $(this).find('div[data-role="header"]')).height());

        //set page to height of window
        $(this).height(window_height);
        $(this).find('div[data-role="content"]').height(th);
    } else {
        //set page to height of window to auto so page does not cut-off at screen height
        $(this).height('auto');
        $(this).find('div[data-role="content"]').height('auto');
    }
});
```